ASP.NET Core authentication and authorization in micro services
I would like to have authentication performed in a separate micro service. At the same time, my authorization micro service is not an identity provider, but rather a simple API.
How can I configure which endpoint in ASP.NET Core to use for authentication and what data to send to it before accessing the destination endpoint?
I found the following method in the documentation:
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        // base-address of your identityserver
        options.Authority = "https://demo.identityserver.io";

        // name of the API resource
        options.Audience = "api1";
    });

Do I understand correctly that this is what I need, but it uses an identity server?
How can I accomplish this without using one?

I'm not able to understand this question well How can I configure which endpoint in ASP.NET Core to use for authentication and what data to send to it before accessing the destination endpoint? --> Per my understanding, authentication is user sign in and authorization is validating whether the current request is allowed to access the destination. Then we should know the url to the login page which should allow anonymous accessing, then we should design how to validate the incoming request, maybe based on cookie/token/userid/role etc.

what you have in your code snippets is a jwt authorization, which allows you to validate the bearer token in the request header of the incoming request. Here's a sample for jwt authentication, you might take a look at it. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/jwt-authentication-with-refresh-tokens-in-net-6-0/

@TinyWang
I apologize for the poor question. I am actually trying to understand what happens behind the scenes when authentication occurs on another server, such as in the Identity Server that is located in a Docker container. Is this a type of authentication endpoint request, or..?
After doing some research, I have figured out the difference between authentication and authorization. By adding authentication to the gateway, I understand it better.
But the question about authentication on another server remained.

such as in the Identity Server that is located in a Docker container -> trying to understand how an identity provider work for authentication? If so,l we might narrow down the issue, like how Azure AD/Google auth do the authentication for web applications. But the whole progress shall be, web app redirect to external auth provider login page, then use the corresponding accounts to sign in, then the auth provider redirect back to the web app along with a credential which informed the app that the sign-in is successful and the user profile.

@TinyWang And am I understanding correctly that all of this is configured within the authentication middleware? Specifically, which endpoint does the authentication process redirect to and in what format is the authenticated user's information received in the response?
Should I delve into this topic, or would it be better to keep authentication within the API gateway project container instead of creating a separate container for it?

Are you trying to write a custom authentication mechanism? Let's say if we are trying to integrate Azure AD into your application so that we could use microsoft account to sign in your application, then there's built-in SDK for us which is not an authentication middleware, if you are trying to write your own authentication, then that depends on whether you want to have an authentication middleware. Could you pls let us know your ultimate goal?

You can try the new Duende Identity Server from Microsoft. This is mentioned in the official ASP.NET Core documentation here.
